# Check that two math expressions are equal

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

Is there an easy algorithm for check two expressions for equality?  For example, it must detect that expressions "x + 5" and "5 + x" are equal and equations "y = x + 5" and "y = 5 + x"? are the same. 
I'll implement algorithm on C# so, any links to code examples will be extremely useful.

Comment: you are getting them as strings I take it?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of right now, would be to put your formula into a tree, then see if the trees are equal.

Comment: Would you need to check if "y-x = 5" as well?

Comment: What about `2y = 2x + 10`?

Comment: Perhaps you can look at one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_linear_algebra_libraries) if you need anything heavy weight (disclaimer:i have no idea if they will help)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge I don't think this has ever been attempted in good, let alone, full generality. Testing for parametric equality (e.g. y = x + 5, 2y = 10 + 2x) needs thought.

Comment: Are they always this simple (i.e., two operands and one operator)?

Comment: In the general case this is practically impossible. You can encode arbitrarily complex problems in a mathematical expression. So unless you restrict yourself to a simple subset (such as polynomials) any algorithm will either not terminate for some inputs or return "I don't know"

Comment: Are you interested in the commutative property only, or an expression like this (a+b)^2 and a^2+2ab+b^2 must be considered the same too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to generate a prefix expression, and the traverse it , and for each binary operator check if the operands match.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can parse your expressions into trees and compare the trees
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree